# Property of object not initialized with ng-init

Tags: angularjs

## Whats wrong in the following AngularJs code? why I am not getting any value for z?

There is something wrong with this JSON object or my Angularjs code, pls rectify it.

```
<div  ng-init="value={x:10, y:78, z:(x + y)}" >
<p>{{'Ashutosh'}}</p>
<p> Age : {{value.x}}</p>
<p> Height is : {{value.y}}</p>
<p> Salary is : {{value.z}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve that using below code.

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body  ng-app>
    <div ng-init="value={x:10, y:78}; value.z = value.x + value.y">
        <p>{{'Ashutosh'}}</p>
        <p> Age : {{value.x}}</p>
        <p> Height is : {{value.y}}</p>
        <p> Salary is : {{value.z}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve that using below code.

```
<div  ng-init="value={x:10, y:78}">
    <div ng-init="value.z = value.x + value.y">
        <p>{{'Ashutosh'}}</p>
        <p> Age : {{value.x}}</p>
        <p> Height is : {{value.y}}</p>
        <p> Salary is : {{value.z}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your code is not getting x & y value in z because they still are not init because x,y & z are in same line so you can use multi line code like above example